# Scala's for comprehensions with Future[Option] with no exceptions

Tags: scala, option-type, future, for-comprehension

I have one Future[Option[String]] function. I need get a transformed string only if future was succesfull and string exists. In other cases I need to get just a None (no any errors or exceptions)

I tried to use for comprehensions (as well as maps/flatMaps) but apparently my result is type Nothing instead of Option[String].

```
def getOption: Option[String]
def getOptionResult: Future[Option[String]]
def someActions: String

val resultO: Option[String] = for {
  myString: String <- getOption
  optionResult: Option[String] <- getOptionResult
  result: String <- optionResult
} yield {
  someActions(result)
}
```

What's the most elegant way to deal with such situations?

Comment: In your example code, what is the purpose of `myString`? What is the return type of `someActions()`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

 def getOptionResult: Future[Option[String]] = Future(Some("Foo"))
 //    def getOptionResult: Future[Option[String]] = Future(None)

val d = getOptionResult.map(a => a.map(r => "(" + r + ")"))

val res = Await.result(d, 100 nanos).getOrElse(None)
```

Comment: result will not be String it will be io.Serializable

Answer (score 0):

```
getOptionResult.recover { case _ => None }
```

if I understood your requirement correctly. This will give an always successful future which has the same result as `getOptionResult` if that succeeds and `None` if it fails. See [the docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html#recover[U%3E:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U]).

Generally you don't want to specify types on the left of `<-`, it doesn't work at all like specifying them for `val/var/def` but turns into a pattern match instead.